# Failing over to mirror instance when not using a witness server

Tags: sql-server, failover, failovercluster

I have a set up where I have two SQL servers set up for failover mirroring to two other SQL servers.

I am not using a witness server.

I had previously used a witness server and that of course would automatically failover the databases when the primary would go down.

Now without using a witness database, how do you manually failover?

If I right-click the database on the mirror instance and click Tasks > Mirror, just get the database properties window, no option to "failover" or make the mirror the primary instance.

Of course if I do the same from the primary database I get the option to failover to the mirror but I obviously can't do this if the primary server is down.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct mirroring phase begin using restore database with norecovery option. So you should restore database with recovery